# How to add an image to JPanel that is in a JPanel?

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I have 7 `JPanel` containers in total. I'd like to add a png image that I generate, or buffer it with the help of the button(charger image) in the JPanel(imagePan)

Most of the examples I've seen so far in the Swing Tutorials use `ImageIcon`

1. The images generated are at **326X254**
2. How to properly add an image to a panel?

Here you'll find the code generating the window below:

```
   import java.awt.BorderLayout;
   import java.awt.Dimension;
   import java.awt.GridLayout;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.OutputStream;
   import java.io.PrintStream;

   import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
   import javax.swing.Box;
   import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
   import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.JTextArea;
   import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
   import javax.swing.border.Border;

   public class View {
   private JFrame frame;
   private JPanel globalPan, firstHorisontalPan, secondhorisontalPan, 
   calibrationPan, imagePan, manipPan, solutionPan; // susp
   private JButton raproche, ecarter, sauvgarder, demarrer, stop, charger;
   private BorderLayout BorderGlobalePan, BorderSecondPane, BorderManipPane, 
   BorderFirstHorisontalPan, BorderResolPan, BorderCalibPan, 
   BorderChargerPan;
    private JTextArea console;
    private Box calibrationBox, solutionBox;


    public void init() {
    // declaration de JFrame
    frame = new JFrame("Rubi's Cube IHM");

    // JPanle
    globalPan = new JPanel();
    firstHorisontalPan = new JPanel();
    secondhorisontalPan = new JPanel();
    imagePan = new JPanel();
    manipPan = new JPanel();
    calibrationPan = new JPanel();
    solutionPan = new JPanel();

    //
    calibrationBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    solutionBox = Box.createVerticalBox();

    // borderLayout
    BorderGlobalePan = new BorderLayout();
    BorderSecondPane = new BorderLayout();
    BorderManipPane = new BorderLayout();
    BorderFirstHorisontalPan = new BorderLayout();
    BorderResolPan = new BorderLayout();
    BorderCalibPan =new BorderLayout();
    BorderChargerPan = new BorderLayout();

    // JButton
    raproche = new JButton("raprocher");
    ecarter = new JButton("ecarter");
    sauvgarder = new JButton("sauvgarder");
    demarrer = new JButton("demarrer");
    stop = new JButton("stop");
    charger = new JButton("charger image");

    console = new JTextArea();

    //add  JPanel names
    firstHorisontalPan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Etat"));
    calibrationPan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("calibration"));
    solutionPan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("résolution & manipulation"));
    imagePan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("visualisation"));

    // definition of JButton size
    raproche.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    ecarter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    sauvgarder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    demarrer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    stop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    charger.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));

    //definition of JPanel size
    globalPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
    firstHorisontalPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 130));
    secondhorisontalPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 480));
    imagePan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, 480));
    manipPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 480));
    calibrationPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    solutionPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

    calibrationBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    solutionBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

    firstHorisontalPan.setLayout(BorderFirstHorisontalPan);
    firstHorisontalPan.add(console);
    //image



    // JPane calibration
    calibrationBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    calibrationBox.add(raproche);
    calibrationBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    calibrationBox.add(ecarter);
    calibrationBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    calibrationBox.add(sauvgarder);

    calibrationPan.setLayout(BorderCalibPan);
    calibrationPan.add(calibrationBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // JPane resolution & manipulation
    solutionBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    solutionBox.add(demarrer);
    solutionBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    solutionBox.add(stop);

    solutionPan.setLayout(BorderResolPan);
    solutionPan.add(solutionBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    //JPane ManipPane
    manipPan.setLayout(BorderManipPane);
    manipPan.add(calibrationPan, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    BorderManipPane.setVgap(20);
    manipPan.add(solutionPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //JPane secondPane
    secondhorisontalPan.setLayout(BorderSecondPane);
    secondhorisontalPan.add(manipPan, BorderLayout.WEST);
    BorderSecondPane.setHgap(7);
    secondhorisontalPan.add(imagePan, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //JPane GlobalHorisontalPane
    globalPan.setLayout(BorderGlobalePan);
    globalPan.add(firstHorisontalPan, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    BorderGlobalePan.setVgap(10);
    globalPan.add(secondhorisontalPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Jpane imagePan
    BorderChargerPan.setVgap(10);
    imagePan.add(charger);

    // window
    frame.add(globalPan);
    frame.setSize(1024, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("cubeBerry");
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

[IHM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HslVs.png)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to proprely add an image to a Jpanel?

1. Create an `ImageIcon`.
2. Add the icon to a `JLabel`.
3. Add the label to the `JPanel`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more information and working examples.

Also, from your posted code, get rid of all the `setPreferredSize()` statements. The layout manager will determine the preferred size of the component. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Let the layout manager do its job.

```
console = new JTextArea();
```

When creating a JTextArea do something like:

```
console = new JTextArea(5, 30);
```

The will suggest the size should be 5 rows and 30 columns. Now the layout manager can calculate a preferred size based on this information.

```
private BorderLayout BorderGlobalePan, BorderSecondPane, BorderManipPane, ...
```

Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most of your variable are correct, but not all. Be consistent!!!

```
frame.setSize(1024, 600);
```

Don't hard code a size. You don't know what the resolution of my computer is. Instead use the `pack()` method and let the layout managers do their job.